# Adding Makefile options into qtcreator project

Tags: c++, c, qt, makefile, qt-creator

I have a project made in qtcreator. The project in itself isn't very important for the question. I would like to add a project called PowerWatershed, the sources are available here:
[PowerWatershed](http://powerwatershed.sourceforge.net/)

Unfortunately, adding all the files to the .pro file give me an error when compiling, when making the "make" command with the Makefile of the PowerWatershed project works.

The makefile of the project is:

```
# Camille Couprie 
# october 2009

OBJDIR  = objects
PINKDIR = PINK
CSDIR   = CSparse
ARGV = argv
PWSRC = src
VPATH = ${PINKDIR}:${CSDIR}:${ARGV}

CSINCLUDE = -I${CSDIR}/Include 
PINKINCLUDE = -I${PINKDIR} 
ARGVINCLUDE = -I${ARGV} 
PWINCLUDE = -Iinclude
INCL = ${CSINCLUDE} ${PINKINCLUDE} ${ARGVINCLUDE} ${PWINCLUDE}

OBJ=    objects/larith.o \
objects/ccsort.o \
objects/cccodimage.o \
objects/gageodesic.o \
objects/mccodimage.o \
objects/mcimage.o \
objects/mcindic.o \
objects/mclifo.o \
objects/random_walker.o \
objects/lMSF.o \
objects/MSF_RW.o \
objects/mcrbt.o \
objects/union_find.o \
objects/image_toolbox.o \
objects/cs_lu.o \
objects/cs_lusol.o \
objects/cs_malloc.o \
objects/cs_util.o \
objects/cs_multiply.o \
objects/cs_compress.o \
objects/cs_lsolve.o \
objects/cs_scatter.o \
objects/cs_cumsum.o \
objects/cs_sqr.o \
objects/cs_ipvec.o \
objects/cs_amd.o \
objects/cs_permute.o \
objects/cs_transpose.o \
objects/cs_counts.o \
objects/cs_add.o \
objects/cs_etree.o \
objects/cs_leaf.o \
objects/cs_fkeep.o \
objects/cs_tdfs.o \
objects/cs_usolve.o \
objects/cs_spsolve.o \
objects/cs_post.o \
objects/cs_reach.o \
objects/cs_dfs.o \
objects/argv.o  
#   objects/cs_print.o \
#   objects/cs_norm.o \
#   
FLAGS = -g -Wall # -pg 
CXX = g++ 
CC = gcc

OPTIMISE=-O4
WARNINGS=-Wall #-Werror
DEBUG=-g
CXXFLAGS= ${DEBUG} ${WARNINGS} ${OPTIMISE} -Wno-deprecated ${FLAGS}
CFLAGS = ${DEBUG} ${WARNINGS} ${OPTIMISE} ${FLAGS}

all:    ${CS} ${OBJ}
${MAKE} powerwatsegm.exe 

# make with the Intel compiler, a very good complement to gcc/g++
# much more efficient and with better diagnoses
intel: 
${MAKE} CC=icc CXX=icpc all

debug:
${MAKE} OPTIMISE='' all

# remove the asserts and the debug information
production:
${MAKE} DEBUG='' FLAGS="-DNDEBUG" all

clean:
rm -f *.exe; rm -f *~; rm -f $(OBJ);  #rm -f overlay*; rm -f mask*;  

powerwatsegm.exe: ${PWSRC}/powerwatsegm.c  $(OBJ)
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) ${PWSRC}/powerwatsegm.c $(OBJ) -o     powerwatsegm.exe 

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  ${PWSRC}/%.c 
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ${INCL} -c $< -o $@ 

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  ${CSDIR}/Source/%.c ${CSDIR}/Include/cs.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${CSINCLUDE} -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  ${PINKDIR}/%.c
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ${PINKINCLUDE} -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/argv.o:   ${ARGV}/argv.c ${ARGV}/argv.h ${ARGV}/argv_loc.h
$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) ${ARGVINCLUDE} -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/lMSF.o:   ${PWSRC}/lMSF.c ${PINKDIR}/mcimage.h     ${PINKDIR}/mccodimage.h  
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) ${PINKINCLUDE} ${PWINCLUDE} -c ${PWSRC}/lMSF.c -o $@
```

I would like to add th propoer option to my .pro file to make the compilation work. At the moment, my pro file looks like

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Power
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    PW_1.0.1/argv/argv.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_add.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_amd.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_chol.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_cholsol.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_compress.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_counts.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_cumsum.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_dfs.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_etree.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_fkeep.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_ipvec.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_leaf.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_lsolve.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_lu.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_lusol.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_malloc.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_multiply.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_norm.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_permute.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_post.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_print.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_reach.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_scatter.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_spsolve.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_sqr.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_tdfs.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_transpose.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_usolve.c \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Source/cs_util.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/gageodesic.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/larith.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/lMSF.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mccodimage.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcimage.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcindic.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mclifo.c \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcrbt.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/cccodimage.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/ccsort.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/gageodesic.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/image_toolbox.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/lMSF.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/MSF_RW.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/powerwatsegm.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/random_walker.c \
    PW_1.0.1/src/union_find.c

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    PW_1.0.1/argv/argv.h \
    PW_1.0.1/argv/argv_loc.h \
    PW_1.0.1/argv/compat.h \
    PW_1.0.1/argv/conf.h \
    PW_1.0.1/CSparse/Include/cs.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/cccodimage.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/ccsort.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/gageodesic.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/image_toolbox.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/lMSF.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/MSF_RW.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/powerwatsegm.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/random_walker.h \
    PW_1.0.1/include/union_find.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/larith.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mccodimage.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcimage.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcindic.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mclifo.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcrbt.h \
    PW_1.0.1/PINK/mcutil.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

And I have the error:

```
/home/iznogood/Documents/Power/PW_1.0.1/src/gageodesic.c:44: erreur : mccodimage.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mccodimage.h>
                        ^
```

I think this is a matter of path, which are mentionned in the Makefile with:

```
OBJDIR  = objects
PINKDIR = PINK
CSDIR   = CSparse
ARGV = argv
PWSRC = src
VPATH = ${PINKDIR}:${CSDIR}:${ARGV}
```

But I can't manage to add them to the .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant qmake variable is `INCLUDEPATH`.

So, for the following from the original makefile:

```
CSINCLUDE = -I${CSDIR}/Include 
PINKINCLUDE = -I${PINKDIR} 
ARGVINCLUDE = -I${ARGV} 
PWINCLUDE = -Iinclude
INCL = ${CSINCLUDE} ${PINKINCLUDE} ${ARGVINCLUDE} ${PWINCLUDE}
```

would be something like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ${CSDIR}/Include \
               ${PINKDIR} \
               ${ARGV} \
               include
```

This is documented in the [QMake manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) in the [reference pages](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you put me in the right direction. I had a lot to change, the original makefile use g++ and gcc, so I had to use the right one with the right files, and I had to select the files to compile, the makefile does not compile them all. Now, I managed to make it works, thanks to you.